# Implementing a finite state bot with webhook (aiogram):

Tags: python, bots, telegram, aiogram

I just implemented my very first telegram bot with aiogram. I used the finite state example provided in their API documentation. However, I have a pretty major issue. I also need to integrate webhook. How could I do this without making major changes to everything? My version of the code needs to send an image to the user, which is created by utilising the data that the user inputs.
I need to deploy it on Heroku, so there's that.
Here is the example.

```
import logging

import aiogram.utils.markdown as md
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.types import ParseMode
from aiogram.utils import executor

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

API_TOKEN = 'BOT TOKEN HERE'


bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)

storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class Form(StatesGroup):
    name = State()  
    age = State()  
    gender = State()  


@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    
    
    
   
    await Form.name.set()

    await message.reply("Hi there! What's your name?")


@dp.message_handler(state='*', commands='cancel')
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='cancel', ignore_case=True), state='*')
async def cancel_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    
   
    
    current_state = await state.get_state()
    if current_state is None:
        return

    logging.info('Cancelling state %r', current_state)
    
    await state.finish()
    
    await message.reply('Cancelled.', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.name)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    
    Process user name
    
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['name'] = message.text

    await Form.next()
    await message.reply("How old are you?")


@dp.message_handler(lambda message: not message.text.isdigit(), state=Form.age)
async def process_age_invalid(message: types.Message):
    
    
    
    return await message.reply("Age gotta be a number.\nHow old are you? (digits only)")


@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text.isdigit(), state=Form.age)
async def process_age(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    
    await Form.next()
    await state.update_data(age=int(message.text))

   
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, selective=True)
    markup.add("Male", "Female")
    markup.add("Other")

    await message.reply("What is your gender?", reply_markup=markup)


@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text not in ["Male", "Female", "Other"], state=Form.gender)
async def process_gender_invalid(message: types.Message):
    
    
    
    return await message.reply("Bad gender name. Choose your gender from the keyboard.")


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.gender)
async def process_gender(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['gender'] = message.text

        
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()

        
        await bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            md.text(
                md.text('Hi! Nice to meet you,', md.bold(data['name'])),
                md.text('Age:', md.code(data['age'])),
                md.text('Gender:', data['gender']),
                sep='\n',
            ),
            reply_markup=markup,
            parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN,
        )

    
    await state.finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Assuming you mean Heroku, you could use [this boilerplate](https://github.com/aahnik/webhook-aiogram-heroku) and just add your functions to bot.py (and remove the echo function).

Comment: @RJAdriaansen I tried it, but there might be more to add to the code, because Heroku keeps on telling me that my states aren't being stored in memory(?)